# The reason to install JupyterLab in Conda base?

Tags: anaconda, conda, jupyter-lab

You can use conda to install Jupyter Lab,but in most examples, the Jupyter Lab is installed in Base and not each separate conda environment. Is there a reason for this? My thought is because the default access is localhost at port 8888, so if you have a bunch of environment, it might get confusing if you launch multiple instances of Lab.

I tried googling it but have not found an explanation of what the pros and cons would be. For excample, if I install Jupyter Lab in base, wouldn't it be outside of environment.yml and if I share my environment.yml with another team member, they would need to install Jupyter Lab manually?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend *not* installing it in **base**. I always use a dedicated environment for heavy stuff like that. Outside of `conda`, `mamba`, `git`, and Conda extensions (e.g., `conda-build`, `conda-smithy`, `conda-lock`, `conda-suggest`), nothing else goes in **base**.

Comment: I ghink I get what you are saying. Basically keep base completely blank and just create a virtual environment for just Jupyter since it just need to be somewhere.